# What's the proper way to perform simple validations scattered everywhere in a JSF JavaEE application?

Tags: validation, jsf, jakarta-ee

For example, from and to dates (from should be before to), integer ranges (int a should always be smaller that int b), if some checkbox is checked some value should be entered in a textbox etc. etc. There are many forms in our application that takes such kind of input. Where and how to properly validate them and show appropriate error messages without caring about simple validations before doing something all the time?

Validate all of them on client side with javascript? Validate every field at the controller at once when the form is submitted? Validate using ajax + controller methods? Implement some custom annotations to mark fields with various restrictions?

After days of hard work, when your tester friend tells you that in some form a "from" date that's after a "to" date can be entered, this makes a developer sad...

PS: Specifically, how and where would you make a "from - to" date validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apart from simple-one-field-only bean validation, IMHO there are only 2 cases:

1. validation type is specific for just one situation: use backing bean method to validate
2. validation type is generic or for a frequent situation: build your own validator tag

i never use client validation, because it is not trustable.

for point 2, this is my cross date validator:

```
@FacesValidator(DateValidator.VALIDATOR_ID)
public class DateValidator implements Validator, PartialStateHolder
{
    public static final String VALIDATOR_ID = "it.shape.DateValidator";
    public static final String BEFORE_MESSAGE_ID = VALIDATOR_ID + ".BEFORE";
    public static final String AFTER_MESSAGE_ID = VALIDATOR_ID + ".AFTER";

    private boolean transientValue = false;
    private boolean initialState;

    private String beforeId;
    private String afterId;

    public DateValidator()
    {
        super();
    }

    public DateValidator(String beforeId)
    {
        super();
        setBeforeId(beforeId);
    }

    public DateValidator(String beforeId, String afterId)
    {
        super();
        setBeforeId(beforeId);
        setAfterId(afterId);
    }

    public String getBeforeId()
    {
        return beforeId;
    }

    public void setBeforeId(String beforeId)
    {

        clearInitialState();
        this.beforeId = beforeId;

    }

    public String getAfterId()
    {
        return afterId;
    }

    public void setAfterId(String afterId)
    {
        clearInitialState();
        this.afterId = afterId;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException
    {
        if((context == null) || (component == null))
        {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        if(value != null)
        {
            if(!(value instanceof Date))
            {
                throw new FaceletException("component [" + component.getClientId() + "] must have a Date value");
            }

            Date currentDate = (Date) value;

            if(beforeId != null)
            {
                UIComponent target = component.findComponent(beforeId);

                if(target == null)
                {
                    throw new FaceletException("component [" + beforeId + "] not found!");
                }

                if(!(target instanceof ValueHolder))
                {
                    throw new FaceletException("component [" + beforeId + "] must be a ValueHolder");
                }

                Object targetValue = ((ValueHolder) target).getValue();

                if(targetValue != null)
                {
                    if(!(targetValue instanceof Date))
                    {
                        throw new FaceletException("component [" + beforeId + "] must have a Date value");
                    }

                    Date targetDate = (Date) targetValue;

                    if(!currentDate.before(targetDate))
                    {
                        throw new ValidatorException(MessageUtils.getErrorMessage(BEFORE_MESSAGE_ID, MessageFactory.getLabel(context, target), DateFormat.getInstance().format(targetDate)));
                    }
                }

            }

            if(afterId != null)
            {
                UIComponent target = component.findComponent(afterId);

                if(target == null)
                {
                    throw new FaceletException("component [" + afterId + "] not found!");
                }

                if(!(target instanceof ValueHolder))
                {
                    throw new FaceletException("component [" + afterId + "] must be a ValueHolder");
                }

                Object targetValue = ((ValueHolder) target).getValue();

                if(targetValue != null)
                {
                    if(!(targetValue instanceof Date))
                    {
                        throw new FaceletException("component [" + afterId + "] must have a Date value");
                    }

                    Date targetDate = (Date) targetValue;

                    if(!currentDate.after(targetDate))
                    {
                        throw new ValidatorException(MessageUtils.getErrorMessage(AFTER_MESSAGE_ID, MessageFactory.getLabel(context, target), DateFormat.getInstance().format(targetDate)));
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object saveState(FacesContext context)
    {
        if(context == null)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        if(!initialStateMarked())
        {
            Object values[] = new Object[2];
            values[0] = beforeId;
            values[1] = afterId;
            return(values);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(FacesContext context, Object state)
    {
        if(context == null)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        if(state != null)
        {
            Object values[] = (Object[]) state;
            beforeId = (String) values[0];
            afterId = (String) values[1];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTransient()
    {
        return(transientValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTransient(boolean transientValue)
    {
        this.transientValue = transientValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void markInitialState()
    {
        initialState = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean initialStateMarked()
    {
        return initialState;
    }

    @Override
    public void clearInitialState()
    {
        initialState = false;
    }
}
```

register in taglib:

```
<tag>
    <description><![CDATA[cross field date validator]]></description>
    <tag-name>validateDate</tag-name>
    <validator>
        <validator-id>it.shape.DateValidator</validator-id>
    </validator>
    <attribute>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[The component identifier for 'before' testing]]>
        </description>
        <name>beforeId</name>
        <required>false</required>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[The component identifier for 'after' testing]]>
        </description>
        <name>afterId</name>
        <required>false</required>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

enjoy:

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.startDate}" />
<h:panelGroup>
    <p:calendar id="startDate" value="#{page.entity.startDate}"
        label="#{bundle.startDate}" />
    <p:message for="startDate" />
</h:panelGroup>

<h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.endDate}" />
<h:panelGroup>
    <p:calendar id="endDate" value="#{page.entity.endDate}">
        <s:validateDate afterId="startDate" />
    </p:calendar>
    <p:message for="endDate" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Ahh life... May I ask, what's the purpose of using PartialStateHolder?

Comment: from [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html): _Validator implementations must have a zero-arguments public constructor. In addition, if the Validator class wishes to have configuration property values saved and restored with the view, the implementation must also implement StateHolder._

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can be disabled using firebug. Jsf has validators and there's that jsr for bean validation.  Some validations are complex and need context of other objects and is usually performed in the business layer. I don't think there's a standard way, but a combination of many.